# How make Firefox see changes to .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, caching

I created an aspx page and viewed it in Firefox and it worked correctly, running the code. But when I make changes to the page (including deleting everything and serving up a blank page), Firefox continues to show the original compiled aspx page! How can I get it to see the new page?

I even added the following code, but it still loads the original page:

```
<script runat="server">
Sub Page_Load
    Random rd = new Random();
    Response.AddHeader("ETag", rd.Next(1111111, 9999999).ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    Response.Expires = -1;
End Sub
</script>
```

I even cleared Firefox's cache, but it still loads the original version!

**EDIT: It appears the issue might be on the ASP.Net side. It's also not changing in Chrome. So, how do I force changes to an aspx file to force a recompiling?**

Comment: What I normally do is just disable the cache on my development machines. problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck with the following code:

```
// Stop Caching in IE
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);

// Stop Caching in Firefox
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Also, your browser may have already cached it prior to when you added the cache prevention code. If so, try hitting CTRL-SHIFT-R in Firefox to force a reload without hitting the cache and see if you still have a problem with Firefox storing cached copies of your page.

Comment: ctrl-shift-r still loads the old version! What could that mean?

Comment: And adding some arbitrary value to the querystring also shows the old version of the page!

Comment: It appears the issue might be on the ASP.Net side. It's also not changing in Chrome. So, how do I force changes to an aspx file to force a recompiling?

Answer (score 0):

- Yet another way to reload and override cache [`CTRL + F5`](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly)
- It may also depend on how you are developing your ASP.Net application/site

  - re-compiling after making changes before viewing again?

---

If you are building a `web application`, you have to *rebuild* (In Visual Studio) your application to reflect any change(s) you made to *server side* code - this isn't an "ASP.Net issue" it's the norm. You can make changes to the HTML (client side) without re-building, but any server code change will need a rebuild (recompile the dll(s)).

The sample code you have above however, looks like `in-line` code - is all your code `in-line` - as in you don't have `code behind` files (i.e. foo.aspx.vb or foo.aspx.cs)?

All the above is based on **local development** - obviously if you are viewing your "production"/live site, then it goes without saying that you have to "push"/"publish"/upload/update, whatever local changes you made to it.

Comment: It appears the issue might be on the ASP.Net side. It's also not changing in Chrome. So, how do I force changes to an aspx file to force a recompiling?

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears the issue is not firefox related but something in the ASP.Net web server (since it happens in Chrome as well), I've asked a different question and will close this one.